# Java generics query (Upper Bounded Wildcards)

Tags: java, generics

Consider below scenario, Class FastCar extends from Car Class:

```
public class FastCar extends Car {}
```

Code snippet in main method:

```
Set<? extends Car> mySet6 = null;
mySet6.add(new FastCar()); //<-----compile error
```

Compile Error Details:

```
(The method add(capture#4-of ? extends Car) in the type Set<capture#4-of ? 
extends Car> is not applicable for )
```

I'm confused why FastCar object can't put into the "set of object extends Car", anyone can help to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Because the dynamic type of mySet might be List<SlowCar>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of generics is to provide type-safe operations (and disallow non-type-safe operations).

For a variable of type `Set<? extends Car>` the compiler allows to assign a value of type `Set<SlowCar>` because `Set<SlowCar>` extends `Set<? extends Car>`. If you would do this, adding a `FastCar` to a `Set` allowing only `SlowCar`s would obviously be an error. Therefore adding a `FastCar` to a `Set` allowing `? extends Car` must also not be allowed because it is not type-safe.

```
Set<SlowCar> slowSet = ...;

slowSet.add(new FastCar()); // Obviously ERROR, FastCar does not extend SlowCar

Set<? extends Car> carSet = slowSet; // Allowed, valid (SlowCar extends Car)

carSet.add(new FastCar());   // Error, because carSet might be
                             // and actually is a set of SlowCars
```

In your case `Set<Car>` should be used:

```
Set<Car> cars = ...;

cars.add(new FastCar());   // Valid, FastCar extends Car
cars.add(new SlowCar());   // Valid, SlowCar extends Car
```

Answer (score 1):

This case is good explained in [Java Tutorials about wildcars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). I will just reformulate it (I renamed types and objects names):

You should be able to figure out why the code above is disallowed. The
type of the parameter to `mySet6.add()` is `? extends Car` -- an
unknown subtype of `Car`. Since we don't know what type it is, we
don't know if it is a supertype of `FastCar`; it might or might not be
such a supertype, so it isn't safe to pass a `FastCar` there.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html